# How to check if element is clicked when click event is bounded to document

Tags: jquery

I want to detect the click on the button, but event target is the image instead of the button. So, how can I detect the click on a specific element when one of its children is clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', function(event){
    var $this=$('#menu'); 
    var $that=$('#menu-body');
    if($this.is(event.target)) { // this line does not work correctly
        if($that.is(':hidden')){
            $that.show();
        } else {
            $that.hide();
        }
    } else {
        if(!$(event.target).is($that)){
            $that.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

This code works when the button has no children, but ain't working when an image is inside:

```
<button id="menu"><img src="pics/menu.png"></button>
```

Comment: To check if button is clicked you go with `if( $(this).attr('id')=='menu' ) { ... } else { ... };`

Comment: `if($(this).attr('id')=='menu') or if(event.target.id=='menu') ` does not work.

Comment: Would like to post it as an answer, but cannot while the questions is on hold... check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezru8qdp/).

Comment: Works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do using plain vanilla Javascript.

Simply check if the element has `id="menu"`, or `closest('#menu')` finds an element. If either is true, you have a click on `#menu` or a descendant.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id === 'menu' || event.target.closest('#menu')) {
    console.log('clicked #menu or descendant');
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="menu"><img src="pics/menu.png"></button>
```